# AVAudioPlayer and UIImagePickerController no more volume rocker

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, avaudioplayer

my problem is that I am using `AVAudioPlayer` to playback sound.
Everything fine till this point!
If I add a `UIImagePickerController` with sourceType `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`,
my volume rockers wont show up anymore.
Any idea?

Comment: I have an app with AVAudioPlayer  and UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and the volume rockers work fine on some phones but not on others. Still trying to figure out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588344/avaudioplayer-volume-buttons-work-on-some-devices-and-not-others

Comment: Already fixed my prob... Do not use UIImagePickerController use now the lowlevel capture interface

Comment: @Ray T: hi thanks for the comment above... gives me a little insight.. however could you please explain the details as a post to your question and then accept your own post as the correct answer... this is so that people like my selves right now can figure out and learn how you have solved your problem by using the lowlevel capture interface.. perhaps paste some code or an explanation of how you got it to work from beginning to end so that others may follow the same procedure. im currently stuck with this myself... and would like a detailed follow up